# function start to run in the first second of the minute

Tags: python, function, time

I want a function start to run in the first second of the minute but i can't do it
this is my code

```
    import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
while not (now.second == "01"):now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: what do you mean run in the first second of the minute? do you mean run once a minute on the minute?

Comment: there is a lot not being explained here. what's the end goal?

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't work because you're comparing a number (`now.second`) to a string `"01"`. In Python numbers and their string representations are not equal (unlike some other programming languages), so this will never work.

Try comparing with `1` (or maybe `0` if you really want the top of the minute). And maybe instead of busy-looping (which will use all of one core of your CPU while waiting), you should perhaps instead use `time.sleep` to wait until the start of the next minute.

```
import datetime
import time

now = datetime.datetime.now()
sec = now.second
if sec != 0:
    time.sleep(60-sec)
# it should be (close to) the top of the minute here!
```

There's always some unpredictability when dealing with time on a computer, since your program might be delayed from running by the OS at any moment (more likely if your CPU is very busy). I'd not worry about it too much though, likely it's good enough to be very close to the right time.

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
while True:
    if time.strftime("%S") == "01":
        #Run Your Code
        time.sleep(59)
```

Answer (score 1):

That would pound your system like crazy, give it a little room to breathe:

```
import time

while True:
    current_seconds = time.gmtime().tm_sec
    if current_seconds == 1:
        print("The first second of a minute...")
    time.sleep(0.9)  # wait at least 900ms before checking again
```

You can further streamline it by calculating how much time to wait before you start checking again - if you're interested only in the first second you can safely sleep until the end of the minute.